# Excel Function Counting Cells with Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, nested, matching

I new at using Excel and need help. I have a sheet that contains operations and headers that represent names but for confidentiality it is letters. What I am trying to do is find the max,min within each operation(rows) between A - O and avoiding the sum and ops ID numbers; however, if I were to insert a column P is there a way to be able to count that?

I tried using =MAX(2:2) and gives me the the operation ID which isn't what I want. I tried =MAX(C2:Q2) it gives me the max value, but it I add a column P it doesn't take that into account.I was thinking creating an index of A-P and using it to match the index with the headers and find the max within that criteria, but I am just not sure how to do it or if there is a simpler way of doing it.

[image]

Comment: In your Max function you have used `=MAX(C2:Q2)`. You are limiting the columns from C2 to Q2. If you Add new Column P you need to update the formula Accordingly

Comment: Since you are new, I can assure you, you don't need to do that much automatic in your templetes. What @Roshan has suggested that is the best and simple thing to do with.

Comment: first welcome!  the formula will update to include column P if column P is inserted.  the formula will update to `MAX(C2:R2)` this is only true because the column is within the range not on the edges or outside the range

Answer (score 1):

If your version of Excel supports `LAMBDA()` function then can try below functions.

For maximum value `=BYROW(C2:S10,LAMBDA(x,MAX(x)))`
For minimum value`=BYROW(C2:S10,LAMBDA(x,MINIFS(x,x,">0")))`

You have to adjust range for your actual case. If you do not want to show 0 values then have to use `IF()` function inside lambda.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are mistaking in your analysis: when you have a formula `=MAX(C2:Q2)` and you add a column "P", then that column does get taken into account, as you can see from the following example, based on formula `=MAX(B2:E2)`:

[image]

Now add an extra column, before "D":

[image]

You see that the formula has changed from `=MAX(B2:E2)` to `=MAX(B2:F2)`.

Answer (score -1):

In your Max function you have used =MAX(C2:Q2).
You are limiting the columns from C2 to Q2. If you Add new Column P you need to update the formula Accordingly.

> OR

You write a formula to Include other empty columns something like `=MAX(C2:Z2)`. This way if any new column Added the formula will Automatically pick that column values.

Comment: to @Dominique's point this is inaccurate. if a column is added within the range the max is looking at the max will automatically include that column. it would be true if a column were added outside or at the edge of the range.